# Conditionally adding term and multi_match filters to elasticsearch with nodejs client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 7.9 with a nodejs client. I have the following query :

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        { "terms" : { "id" : ["5f0d06fb5112231eb89eb819", "5f0d06fb5112231eb89eb817"] } },
        {"query_string": {
            "query": "(News) OR (Entertainent)",
            "fields": [ "topics", "subTopics", "categories"]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
              "query": "publisher",
              "fields": ["text",  "name", "title", "subtitle", "description"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to conditionally add the terms filter for id if list of ids coming in to the nodejs/js function is not empty. Similarly for the multi_match query text as well. Add the multi_filter only if the incoming text is not empty
Should all queries be pre-constructed or is it possible to have conditional blocks and add only if the empty text or array of Ids are not empty.
My current method expects both ids and text input to the method to have valid values but these could be empty. Do I separate methods to handle the empty conditions

```
    export const searchResults = async (text, ids) => {
  const response = await client.search({
    index: "new_index", //customer.id
    type: "_doc",
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {terms: {"id": ids}},
            {query_string: {
                query: "(News) OR (Entertainent)",
                fields: [ "topics", "subTopics", "categories"]
              }
            },
            {
              multi_match: {
                  query: text,
                  fields: ["text",  "name", "title", "subtitle", "description"],
              }
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    },
  });
  return response?.hits?.hits.map(({_source}) => _source) || [];
};
```

any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment and managing client based applications you should use [search-templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html), where you can use conditional blocks of queries. Besides, if you would want to change your query you would not neet to redeploy your app, just change it on ES.